Creating a state by state map in R to show the number of survey responses by state, I'm using tidyverse and my map does display but has weird shapes
I'm using the following code but I do not get a state by state density map for the variable 'Group' or "Group2" instead I get the USA map with all kinds of weird angles and triangles embedded crossing state lines.
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 16))

install.packages("foreign")
library("foreign")

data1 <- read.spss("C:/afp/density2.sav", to.data.frame = TRUE)

head(data1)
state_initial                    states Group Group2 Sum2023
1            AL alabama                     2.1      1       3
2            AK alaska                      0.0      0       0
3            AZ arizona                     1.0      3       6
4            AR arkansas                    4.0      3       2
5            CA california                  1.0     20      15
6            CO colorado                    6.0      4       5

us_states <- map_data("state")

us_states %>%
  left_join(data1, by = c("region" = "states")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = Group, fill = Group)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "gray90", size = 0.1) +
  coord_map(projection = "albers", lat0 = 45, lat1 = 55) +
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "gradient") +
  theme(
    legend.position = "right",
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank()
  )



Try with group=group to group and draw the polygons by the group column from the map data not the Group column from your dataset. For more help please share your data using dput(See e.g. How to make a great R reproducible example) and please do not copy & paste code from the console. Instead copy & paste the code from your  script and format it as a code block.
